# The right way to store data into database in a wordpress plugin

Tags: php, html, wordpress, insert, sql-insert

I created this plugin for a Wordpress site, in the admin page i've insert a modal that can change a specific #color in css only if it's pressed the specific color button.

With the code below, i need to reload two times the admin page for see the change, so i think it's not the correct way to insert - update values displayed. This code it's placed on the same file where modal it's declare.

Please, can you show me the wordpress right way to update or insert data into database then show the change in admin page?

Thanks.

```php
function recensility_system_action_color_fest($id ,  $title, $footer )
{
global $wpdb;

$colors = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT *  FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'recensility_color_fest', ARRAY_A);
?>
<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="recensility-modal">
<!-- Modal content -->
<div id="<?php echo $id.'-insert'; ?>" class="recensility-modal-content">
  <div class="recensility-modal-header">
<span id="<?php echo $id.'-close'; ?>" class="recensility-modal-close" onclick="close_modal('<?php echo $id; ?>')">&times;</span>
<h2 class="recensility-modal-title"><i class="fas fa-swatchbook"></i><?php echo $title; ?></h2>
  </div>
  <div class="recensility-modal-body">
<center>
<h2>Clicca sul colore da impostare</h2>
<div class="recensility-color-fest-chooser">
<form id="recensility-color-fest-form" method="post">
   <div class="recensility-color-fest-chooser-body">
   <div class="recensility-color-fest-chooser-items">
   <?php 
   foreach ($colors as $color){
   ?>
<div class="dot-container <?php echo ($color['is_active']=='true') ? 'dot-active' : 'dot-inactive'; ?>">
   <?php 
   echo 
   ($color['is_active']=='true') 
   ? 
  '<p class="dot-active-text">Attivo</p>' 
   :
  '<button id="recensility-color-fest-form-submit" name="recensility-color-fest-form-submit" class="recensility-color-fest-form-button" value="'. $color['value'].'" type="submit" form="recensility-color-fest-form">';
?>
  <span  class="dot" style="background-color:<?php echo $color['value'] ?>"></span>
  <?php echo ($color['is_active']=='false') ? '</button>' : ''; ?>
  <p><?php echo $color['name'] ?></p>
</div>
   <?php
   }
   ?>
   </div>
   </div>
</form>
   </div>
 </center>
  </div>
  <div class="recensility-modal-footer">
<h3 class="recensility-modal-footer-content"><?php echo $footer; ?></h3>
  </div>
<?php 
print_r($_POST);
if (!empty($_POST['recensility-color-fest-form-submit'])){
$activeColor = ($wpdb->get_results('SELECT `value` FROM '.$wpdb->prefix.'recensility_color_fest'.' WHERE `is_active` = "true"', ARRAY_A)[0])['value'];

$wpdb->update
(
$wpdb->prefix.'recensility_color_fest',
array('is_active' => 'false'),
array('is_active' => 'true')
);

recensility_color_fest_apply($activeColor, $_POST['recensility-color-fest-form-submit']);

$wpdb->update
(
$wpdb->prefix.'recensility_color_fest',
array('is_active' => 'true'),
array('value' => $_POST['recensility-color-fest-form-submit'])
);
}
?>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
```